# Is 'pserve' inappropriate to serve my Pyramid app for production use behind nginx?

Tags: wsgi, pyramid

I get the impression, though it's not explicitly stated anywhere, that using `pserve` on my Pyramid app when it's deployed to production is not the best idea. I don't know that it deals with concurrency, for example -- and I suspect it doesn't at all. I don't know if `paster` is right, either.

For context: I have a Pyramid app with a PasteDeploy configuration file, which I can serve up using a command like `pserve config.ini`. So, in production, would I just run that command as a daemon and reverse-proxy it through `nginx`?

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pserve` is just an application loader and server runner. It's capable of launching many different WSGI servers (one of which you need to select for deployment). There are few WSGI servers that cannot be run via `pserve` (the main one coming to mind is Apache's mod_wsgi).

As far as production, the main thing you want is reliability, which supervisor can greatly help with. You'll want to look at the [nginx deployment recipe](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html), but the cookbook actually has recipes for several different deployment scenarios which you will need to evaluate based on your current infrastructure.